# Angular mat-autocomplete : How to display the option name and not the value in the input

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-6

I'm using the **`mat-autocomplete`** widget under my Angular app :

```
    <mat-form-field class="col-md-3" color="warn">
                <input type="text"
                       id="libelleShop"
                       #inputSelectShop
                       placeholder="Selectionner la boutique"
                       matInput
                       formControlName="libelleShop"
                       ngDefaultControl
                       [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete"" 
               (optionSelected)="onShopSelectionChanged($event)">
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let shop of shopData" [value]="shop.value">
                    {{shop.name}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-autocomplete>
   </mat-form-field>
```

my Shop data is like this :

```
shopData = [
    {name: 'AAA' , value :'11'},
    {name: 'BBB', value :'22'},
    {name: 'CCC', value : '33'}
  ];
```

Like this -  options are displayed by `name` , but when selection the input displaysit by the `value` not the `name`.

Knowing that i need the value for other treatment and i won't change the `[value]` in the `mat-automplete`.

How may i take reference for the name to the input ??

Suggestions ??

Answer (score 17):

You can use the displayWith attribute of Mat autocomplete and pass in a function that will return the desired formatted string.

In your example:

```js
displayFn(shop: Shop): string {
  return shop.name;
}
```

```html
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete"" (optionSelected)="onShopSelectionChanged($event)" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let shop of shopData" [value]="shop">
      {{shop.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: This won't work because of `[value]="shop.value"` which the OP doesn't want to change. Also, `displayWith` is a feature on mat-autocomplete, not mat-option.

Comment: Indeed my mistake, said it in the answer but not in the code... Anyway the lookup is the right solution in that case :)

Comment: this useful for me, only fix => [value]="shop"

Comment: I used this method for some reason the name is not getting displayed when I select a name but in the console it prints the value property. Can someone please help!!

Comment: Are you passing [value]="shop" instead of [value]="shop.value" ?

Comment: You saved me. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Simple way by using option **id** mayby useful:

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onShopSelectionChanged($event)">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let shop of shopData" [value]="shop.name" [id]="shop.value">
    {{shop.name}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

and read value & name in the function:

```
onShopSelectionChanged(event) {
    const selectedValue = event.option.id;
    console.log(selectedValue);
    const selectedName = event.option.value;
    console.log(selectedName);
}
```

Comment: Very helpful when we want to process another value rather than a displayed value.

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't want to change `[value]="shop.value"`, your only resort is to lookup the name based on value in a function used with the `displayWith` feature:

```
<mat-autocomplete ... [displayWith]="getShopName" ... >


getShopName(value) {
    const results = this.shopData.filter(shop => shop.value === value);
    if (results.length) {
        return results[0].name;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: This works fine except when names are duplicated although the Ids are unique

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FormControl` on `input` tag and can change the value of this `form-control` using `patchValue` method.

Use `(onSelectionChange)="onEnter($event)"` and find the selectedArray option using the selected value, and from that selected option object update the value of input with any of the options key.

Html :

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input #stateInput (keyup)="0" matInput placeholder="State" 
     aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="stateInput.value !=undefined && 
      onEnter($event)" *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async"
      [value]="state.name">
        <img style="vertical-align:middle;" aria-hidden 
         src="{{state.flag}}" height="25" />
        <span>{{ state.name }}</span> |
        <small>Population: {{state.population}}</small>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

---

Ts file :

```
 onEnter(evt: any){
    const selectedState =  this.states.find(state =>
      state.name.toLowerCase()==evt.source.value.toLowerCase());
    if (evt.source.selected) {
      console.log(selectedState);
      if(selectedState) {
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.stateCtrl.patchValue(selectedState.population);
      }, 0);
      }
    }
  }
```

**[Stackblitz Demo with other data](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-input-value-change?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.html)**